# navigation controller without using story boards

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 SecondViewController *testAppViewController2Obj =[[SecondViewController    alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestAppViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:testAppViewController2Obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: i try to use above code but i can't move one view Controller to another.Thanks for comment

Comment: have you implemented navigationcontroller in your project ?

Comment: u mean u added navigation controller in secondView which want to move next view when u pressed it..is it right???

Comment: This isn't really a question ... what exactly are you trying to accomplish and can we see more of your code?

Comment: In other to move from one VC to another you must have linked a navigation controller to your app delegate root view controller. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
ContainerViewController *container = [[ContainerViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:container];

    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 65)];

container.navigationItem.title = @"Frames";
     self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

i hope it works

Answer (score -1):

In order to push a new view controller you should first create a view controller, VC1, link it with a navigation controller and then link the navigation controller to the rootViewController in the AppDelegate

```
 #AppDelegate
 FirstViewController  *VC1 = [FirstViewController new];
 UINavigationController *nVC = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC1];
 self.window.rootViewController = nVC;
```

Then when VC1 gets pushed, you can create another view controller and push it  like this:

```
 #Now in VC1
 SecondViewController *VC2 = [SecondViewController new];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```